# Django, view based permission similar to per object permission

Tags: django

I want to implement view based permissions in same fashion as per object based permissions are applied. I know that when I have a model named A, three permissions can_add, can_edit, can_delete are created which is coupled with A. Now, can I have model that holds similar record but based on view. So, when I say can_view_login_page a permission record is created and when I place it above view as `@method_decorator(permission_required('can_view_login_page'))` it allows or denies access based on role/group? My question might sound vague but I cant figure out how to put it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may not be *exactly* what you are looking for, but there is [`user_passes_test`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.user_passes_test)

You can use this method decorator to check whether a user has the correct credentials in order to see the page

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test

def can_view_login(user):
    return user.can_view_login

@user_passes_test(can_view_login)
def my_view(request):
```

Comment: Its a great thing, something that I can definitely use. Thank you @Sayse

Comment: @RajeshYogeshwar - No worries, enjoy!